# Fontawesome Doesn't show on Chrome

Tags: html, font-awesome

I try to show the Infinity icon by Fontawesome on a web page by this code. I can't see that in Google Chrome but in Firefox show:

```
    <h2> <i class="fa fa-infinity" aria-hidden="true"></i> INFINITY </h2>
```

Google Chrome v77.
Firefox v69.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO Hamid. This is the second time I have seen this issue today.

If you upgrade to Font Awesome 5 you should be okay.

```
<i class="fa fa-infinity"></i> Infinity
```

Here is a [Fiddle for FA 5.11](https://jsfiddle.net/mjpoo/n04gvm79/7/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it just works there, try to use it directly in Chrome web browser and don't forget to use `<h2></h2> tag. I used FA v5.11.2 too.